Why is there a delay when using Automator to create a keyboard shortcut to open Terminal.app on macOS? Any faster alternatives?
I'm trying to set up a keyboard shortcut to quickly open Terminal.app (or any other application) on macOS using Automator and the ~/Library/Services directory, but I've noticed a significant delay each time I press the shortcut. The shortcut works, but there seems to be a 1-2 second delay between pressing the keys and the Terminal opening.
Here's what I did:

Created a workflow in Automator:

I created a service (workflow) named Open Terminal.workflow that runs a simple AppleScript to open the Terminal app.
The script in Automator is as follows:
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
end tell




Assigned a custom keyboard shortcut:

I set up the keyboard shortcut Command + Control + Option + T to trigger the Automator service via System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.



The problem:

The shortcut works, but there is a noticeable delay (1-2 seconds) each time I use it to launch Terminal.app.
I want a faster way to open the Terminal without this delay. Ideally, I'd like an open-source, free solution to quickly launch Terminal or any other app without relying on Automator, as it seems slower.

What I've tried:

Automator works, but the delay is quite noticeable.
System Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts doesn't provide an option to directly map a shortcut to open an app, so I had to use Automator.
I've also tested other workflows in Automator, but the delay persists.

What I'm looking for:

A faster solution (ideally open-source and free) that allows me to quickly launch Terminal.app or other applications using a custom keyboard shortcut, without significant delay.
If there are other tools or scripts that can do this more efficiently than Automator, I'd love to know about them.


Any reason you wouldn't just use Spotlight? Cmd-Space then a couple of characters, and it's instantaneous. Spinning up Automator is always going to be heavy in comparison.

I have not used this tool, so I do not know if it will meet your needs: SRHD, Simple Rust Hotkey Daemon is a minimal and lightweight key binding service for MacOS similar to skhd. It is FOSS.
https://github.com/sylvanfranklin/srhd
I use rcmd, a paid app: https://lowtechguys.com/rcmd/. I hold the right CMD key and press I, and this launches iterm.
And I suspect you are aware of application launchers such as Alfred. While relatively quick, they do require more than just a keyboard shortcut.
